# ¿como puedo obtener el codigo del error en un try catch en laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

tengo un metodo "crear"

```
public function crear(Request $req) {
    $rules = array(
        'nombre' => 'required',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make ( Input::all (), $rules );
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
    }else{
        try{
            $cargos = new Cargos();
            $cargos->nombre = $req->nombre;
            $cargos->save();
            return response()->json($cargos);
        }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
            return $e->getBindings();
        }
    }
}
```

obtengo el valor con jquery

```
        success: function(data) {
            if((data.errors)){
                alert(data.errors.nombre);
            }else{
                if(data){
                    alert("Error: "+data);
                }else{
                    VolverANumerar();
                }
            }
        },
```

pero ese codigo me arroja esto, cuando intento registrar un valor que ya esta registrado en una tabla y el campo tiene restricción de tipo unique:

Error: Operario,2016-11-01 14:55:51,2016-11-01 14:55:51

en la api de laravel consegui que `getBindings()` arroje un código me sirvio con este:

```
    try{
        Cargos::find($req->id)->delete();
        return response()->json();
    }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
        return $e->getBindings();
    }
```

pero con el primero no.

lo que quiero es que en todos los Exception de try/catch me lance un codigo.. es para no mostrarle al usuario un error de sql sino algo que el pueda comprender. con el primer codigo intento registrar un item que ya esta registrado y me devuelve los datos que intente registrar, pero no me devuelve un codigo como tal para yo validarlo. En el ultimo codigo que muestro elimino un item que esta siendo usado en otra tabla y el Exception me arroja un 1.. yo lo valide en la pantalla, si es 1 entonces dile al usuario que esta intentando eliminar un item que esta usado.

no se si aun no me explico bien. disculpen mi torpeza al no saber explicarme bien. Primera vez que comento en un foro xD

De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo exactamente el problema, para saber si se ha podido guardar lo que deberías de comprobar es el `save()`

Por ejemplo:

```
if($cargos->save()) {
    return Response::json(array('success' => true), 200);
}     
return Response::json(array('error' => true), 200);
```

Tampoco necesitas realmente el `} else {` si el validador falla directamente se ejecuta el `return`, por lo que lo puedes dejar así:

```
public function crear(Request $req) {

    $rules = array(
        'nombre' => 'required',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make ( Input::all (), $rules );

    if ($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
    }

    $cargos = new Cargos();
    $cargos->nombre = $req->nombre;

    if($cargos->save()) {
        return Response::json(array('success' => true), 200);
    }     
    return Response::json(array('error' => true), 200);
}
```

En cualquiera de los casos, si quieres lanzar una excepcion cuando no se guarde correctamente, modificas el ultimo `return` con un `throw` para la excepción y listo.

**Edit:** ¿Estas seguro de que estas lanzando la excepción? Porque por lo que comentas, no parece que al eliminar te esté lanzando una excepción, si no que el `1` es porque el `delete` a salido bien.

¿Tienes una captura del error de Laravel?

En cualquiera de los casos, la excepción que estas intentado coger es `\Illuminate\Database\QueryException` por lo que si se lanza alguna otra no le vas a hacer `catch`, o agregas mas o pones una mas genérica para que la puedas coger seguro.

Comment: gracias por la correccion en varios de los errores que tengo :D

Comment: modifique la publicación especificando mas el problema.. o lo q quiero hacer :D

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta, revisa las excepciones.